# funding a wallet

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, wallet, week06

I've created a wallet with create-wallet.sh and loaded it with load-wallet.sh, and its balance is 0:

```
"balance":{"total":{"quantity":0,"unit":"lovelace"},"available":{"quantity":0,"unit":"lovelace"},"reward":{"quantity":0,"unit":"lovelace"}}
```

Lars says in the video that we can connect this wallet to Daedalus or Yoroi and then use the Faucet to fund the wallet. Is there a way to fund the wallet directly, without Daedalus or Yoroi? I have already used Faucet at a previous step, the balance of the address I have used is 999.656267 ADA and I should be able to connect the wallet to these funds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do as follows:

- **create-wallet.sh** (create a new wallet)
- **load-wallet.sh** (load new wallet into wallet-backend)
- **Take id** value from **load-wallet.sh** result.
- Set **WALLETID=id** in your **env.sh**
- `. env.sh` (source env.sh)
- **get_address.sh**  (get the address of the new wallet)
- **Use send.sh** (week03) in order to transfer funds from your funded address to your new address.

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
    --alonzo-era \
    --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
    --change-address <address_with_funds> \
    --tx-in <an_utxo_id_with_funds> \
    --tx-out "<your_new_address> <ada_to_tranfer> lovelace" \
    --out-file tx.body

cardano-cli transaction sign \
    --tx-body-file tx.body \
    --signing-key-file <skey_of_address_with_funds> \
    --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
    --out-file tx.signed

cardano-cli transaction submit \
    --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
    --tx-file tx.signed
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: $ ./sendWallet.sh 
Estimated transaction fee: Lovelace 166953
Transaction successfully submitted.

That's great, it worked, balance is also updated.